# Error play-services-ads Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-adsense

Al Agregar implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'  e iniciar el proyecto se cierra inesperdamente la aplicacion.Cabe recalcar que simeplente agregue esa liobrerfia no tengo nada en el Main.

GRADLE:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.estadosextractor"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
2020-05-29 12:27:37.507 2453-2453/com.example.estadosextractor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.estadosextractor, PID: 2453
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6407)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5949)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyc.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:33)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6402)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al mensaje:

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************
```

no estas inicializando el sdk dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` , debes definir un "app ID" :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value=<app ID>/>
```

---

solo recuerda algo `app Id` no es lo mismo que el `adUnitID` , el `adUnitID` es el que debes configurar en tu `adview`, el que configuras dentro del layout .xml